# Makefile : syntax ?=

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile from Intel in which there is some "?=".
Like

```
COMPILER ?= $(GCC_PATH)g++
```

But

```
EXECUTABLE = run
```

What is the difference between ?= and = and when do I have to use the first one instead of the second one ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoth [the fine documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Setting):

> If you'd like a variable to be set to a value only if it's not already set, then you can use the shorthand operator ‘?=’ instead of ‘=’.

Answer (score 1):

`?=` is for conditional assignment, i.e if it not already defined then only assign the value else leave it. In your example if you give `make COMPILER=arm-none-gcc` then `arm-none-gcc` is used as Compiler than the default g++, if you just type `make` then g++ taken as option for COMPILER. If `=` is used then COMPILER will be assigned  value when and where assignments are encountered. for more on make files you can refer to 
[Understanding makefile for beginners](http://story-of-a-programmer.blogspot.com/2015/04/makefile-tutorial.html)